# Unable to get EKS Ingress to work with Route53 and ELB

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-route53

I am trying to setup a subdomain on EKS with ingress like

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: staging-ingress-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456:certificate/abcdge-XXXXX
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443' 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: nginx-test-alb
spec:
  rules:
  - host: admin.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-test
            port: 
              number: 80
```

and also has the service setup as

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-test
  name: nginx-test
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-test
  type: ClusterIP
```

This is setting up the subdomain in Route53 as

```
cname-admin.test.com TXT=> heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=ZXXXXX,external-dns/resource=service/staging/nginx-test
```

Also no loadbalancer has been created.

When i goto https://admin.test.com it doesnt work, what could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have AWS Load Balancer Controller installed and configured in your cluster?

Comment: I would suggest reviewing that all your alb annotations are valid for the deployed ALB controller version.
You can review the annotation here: [alb annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/).
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` probably not supported.
In addition, I would suggest reviewing your alb controller logs.